# Find index of number from a string in C#

Tags: c#

Form the below string I would like to get the index of the starting number.Please let me know how this can be done in C#.net.

For example

```
University of California, 1980-85.  
University of Colorado, 1999-02
```

Comment: please post your code attempt so far....

Comment: do you want the position of the first number?

Comment: yes, I want to get the first position of the number in each string.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace IndexOfAny
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("University of California, 1980-85".IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any performance issue with this? can it be slow if we loop it for dozens of strings?

Comment: I would take the ToCharArray out of the loop for sure. Otherwise, I imagine this is faster than a regex but I can't be sure. You'll have to performance test.

Comment: @mpen I tried your suggestion just now, and got a compiler error saying that it couldn't convert a `string` to `char[]`. Your suggestion seemed very intuitive, and I'm not sure why that doesn't work, other than that a `string` has all the behavior and properties of a `char[]` without actually being one.

Comment: @krillgar It still works for me: https://ideone.com/QwuF12 You didn't forget to add the `.ToCharArray()` bit did you?

Comment: I misunderstood your comment then. You meant create a variable that is the static character array **before** you get into the loop, instead of creating one in each iteration. Seeing the code in just your answer as it is now, and reading your comment made me think you were trying to avoid the conversion of a `string` to a `char[]`, which could take time. It is required to do that, but do it once.

Comment: @krillgar Yeah, that's exactly what I meant :-)

Answer (score 10):

Following might help you to achieve your task

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\d+");
Match m = re.Match(txtFindNumber.Text);
if (m.Success) 
{
    lblResults.Text = string.Format("RegEx found " + m.Value + " at position " + m.Index.ToString());
}
else 
{
    lblResults.Text = "You didn't enter a string containing a number!";
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if this is the fastest way (I assume it has to be faster than `Regex`) but you can just do it with a 1 liner using the built in string method `IndexOfAny`:

```
string yourString = "University of California, 1980-85";
int index = yourString.IndexOfAny(new char[]
    { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' });
// index = 26
// if nothing found it would be -1
```

**EDIT:** My method seems to be much faster in a simple test I did:

```
string test = "University of California, 1980-85";

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
long totalTicks1 = 0;
long totalTicks2 = 0;
char[] testChars = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
Regex re = new Regex(@"\d+");
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    watch.Reset();
    watch.Start();
    Match m = re.Match(test);
    watch.Stop();
    totalTicks1 += watch.ElapsedTicks;

    watch.Reset();
    watch.Start();
    int index = test.IndexOfAny(testChars);
    watch.Stop();
    totalTicks2 += watch.ElapsedTicks;
}
```

Run result 1:

```
Regex totalTicks1 = 4851
IndexOfAny totalTicks2 = 1472
```

Run result 2:

```
Regex totalTicks1 = 5578
IndexOfAny totalTicks2 = 1470
```

Run result 3:

```
Regex totalTicks1 = 5441
IndexOfAny totalTicks2 = 1481
```

This looks like a significant difference.  I wonder how it would be affected by different lengths of strings as well...  I try to stay away from `Regex` except in situations where I am truly looking for some type of complex pattern as it always seems real slow.

**EDIT 2:** Fixed up test to make it more accurate with the `char[]` and `Regex` predefined outside of the loop.

Comment: you have to run it a few thousand times to get any kind of accuracy, methinks.

Comment: @Mark I just did a test of that... mean while you ninja'd my answer :P