# Determine end point of a sub string by the character type

Tags: c#

Sorry I struggled to come up with a suitable title for this post.Apologies if the title is not clear.

I have number of strings that follow a format like this

```
"Application has been dispatched to the client 5  business day(s) ago. Signed application has not been received"
```

I want to substring this up to the number  5 .

So the result would be

```
 "Application has been dispatched to the client"
```

However, I don't always know how many characters are before the numeric value

Some strings have different messages but the structure is similar. There is always a number.

Another example

```
"Client signed the application 13 day(s) ago."
```

Now in this one, I want to get the following output

```
"Client signed the application"
```

Basically, I need a way to get everything until the numeric value.

How can I do this?

Hope this is clear and thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732808/find-index-of-number-from-a-string-in-c-sharp answer of this question should help you to go forward..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need some regex. Since you want until the numbers, this should work:

```
var regex = new Regex(@" \d+");
var result = input.Substring(0, regex.Match(input).Index));
```

(assumes `input` is your string). This will substring from the start right up until the first digit, excluding the space.

Note that if the string does not not have a digit, then the result will be blank. If you want it to return the whole string in that instance, you can use an `if` statement to test if the match index is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly u can use split() string to convert string value into array

For example :

```
var str = "Client signed the application 13 day(s) ago"; 
var res = str.Split(' '); // split when space found
Console.WriteLine(res[0]); // output value when array index at 0
```

So, the output should be :

```
Client
```

After that u just loop the data in array and when found string data that can be converted into integer, the loop must be stop

```
        int number, index = 0;

        bool result = false; 

        while (result == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(res[index]);
            index++;
            result = Int32.TryParse(res[index], out number);
        }
```

Finally the output Should be

```
Client 
signed 
the 
application
```

Hope my answer can help u

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution!  I had to choose another answer due to its compact nature. But appreciate your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

I like functional programming, so I thought about solving this in F# first. Here is what I came up with:

```
let findNumber (s : string) =
    let rec loop i =
        if i >= s.Length then -1
        elif Core.char.IsDigit s.[i] then i
        else loop (i + 1)
    loop 0

let truncateAtNumber s =
    match findNumber s with
    | -1 -> s
    | p -> (s.Substring (0, p)).Trim ()
```

Short and clean. However, I was surprised that the C# translation is actually shorter (**EDIT:** even shorter now):

```
static string TruncateAtNumber(this string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        if (char.IsDigit(s[i]))
            return s.Substring(0, i).Trim();
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution. I chose the Regex due to its compact nature. But your approach works perfectly too.

Answer (score 1):

```
string result = Regex.Match(str, @"\D*").Value;
```

`\D` matches any non-digit character, and `*` matches it 0 or more times.

or a bit shorter:

```
string result = Regex.Split(str, @"\d")[0];
```